# How bad would it be to keep using uniqueIdentifier in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uniqueidentifier

I am making an app and I see that uniqueIdentifier is deprecated in iOS 5, but I kinda need to identify devices using the app so that I can tell them apart. I tried to access the `uniqueIdentifier` property of `UIDevice` and it still works. Does anyone know how long this will last? Will it work forever?

The reason I don't want to switch to CFUUID is because it will change each time the user installs and uninstalls the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's deprecated - you shouldn't rely on it. It could keep working for years and several new major versions, or it could stop with a minor version in a week's time.

Comment: Ok. I found this https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5 which is awesome and lets you create a UUID based on the device's MAC address and I'm pretty sure some other things.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer here: [Is there any way to identify an iDevice user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631632/is-there-any-way-to-identify-an-idevice-user/8631680#8631680) this should give you and idea of the problem and posible solutions

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5) which is awesome and lets you create a UUID based on the device's MAC address and I'm pretty sure some other things.